# Big O notation from a for loop

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

I encounter this problem in my discrete mathematics class. At first glance, I thought that the answer would be O($2^{(n^{302})}$), since t multiplies 2 every time in the for loop. However the correct answer is O($n^{302}$). I don't know why it work this way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELJXN.png)

Edit: Sorry, please click the image URL.

Comment: The computation for the inner for loop takes $n^{300}$ operations to complete, the outer for loop takes place $n$ times, so it's clear to me that you should get at least $n^{301},$ but I don't know why it should be $n^{302}.$ 

You'll likely get more traction on this if you type out what you've tried, what you understand, and if you provide your problem typed out in pseudo code.

Comment: @Chickenmancer Outer loop runs $n^2 - n$ times.

Comment: Very much appreciated. I see the flaw in my thinking now.